# Using Python in a Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, python

If I try to start python in a bash script, the script will stop running and no commands will execute after "Python" is called. In this simple example, "TESTPRINT" will not be printed. It seems like the script just stops.

```
#!/bin/bash

python

print("TESTPRINT")

Echo
```

How do I make the script continue running after going into Python? I believe I had the same problem a few years ago after writing a script that first needed to shell into an Android Phone. I can't remember how I fixed it that time.

Comment: Note, python may call python2 by default on some distributions. It is often best to be safe and explicitly call python3.

Answer (score 47):

To run a set of Python commands from a `bash` script, you must give the Python interpreter the commands to run, either from a file (Python script) that you create in the script, as in

```bash
#!/bin/bash -e

# Create script as "script.py"
cat >script.py <<'END_SCRIPT'
print("TESTPRINT")
END_SCRIPT

# Run script.py
python script.py

rm script.py
```

(this creates a new file called `script.py` or overwrites that file if it already exists, and then instructs Python to run it; it is then deleted)

... or directly via some form of redirection, for example a here-document:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

python - <<'END_SCRIPT'
print("TESTPRINT")
END_SCRIPT
```

What this does is running `python -` which instructs the Python interpreter to read the script from standard input.  The shell then sends the text of the Python script (delimited by `END_SCRIPT` in the shell script) to the Python process' standard input stream.

Note that the two bits of code above are subtly different in that the second script's Python process has its standard input connected to the script that it's reading, while the first script's Python process is free to read data other than the script from standard input. This matters if your Python code reads from standard input.

Python can also take a set of commands from the command line directly with its `-c` option:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

python -c 'print("TESTPRINT")'
```

What you *can't do* is to "switch to Python" in the middle of a `bash` script.

The commands in a script is executed by `bash` one after the other, and while a command is executing, the script itself waits for it to terminate (if it's not a background job).

This means that your original script would start Python in interactive mode, temporarily suspending the execution of the `bash` script until the Python process terminates.  The script would then try to execute `print("TESTPRINT")` as a shell command.

It's a similar issue with using `ssh` like this in a script:

```
ssh user@server
cd /tmp
ls
```

(which may possibly be similar to what you say you tried a few years ago).

This would *not* connect to the remote system and run the `cd` and `ls` commands there.  It would start an interactive shell on the remote system, and once that shell has terminated (giving control back to the script), `cd` and `ls` would be run locally.

Instead, to execute the commands on a remote machine, use

```
ssh user@server "cd /tmp; ls"
```

(This is a lame example, but you may get the point).

---

The below example shows how you may actually do what you propose.  It comes with several warning label and caveats though, *and you should never ever write code like this* (because it's obfuscated and therefore unmaintainable and, dare I say it, downright bad).

```
python -
print("TESTPRINT")
```

Running it:

```
$ sh -s <script.sh
TESTPRINT
```

What happens here is that the script is being run by `sh -s`.  The `-s` option to `sh` (and to `bash`) tells the shell to execute the shell script arriving over the standard input stream.

The script then starts `python -`, which tells *Python* to run whatever comes in over the standard input stream.  The next thing on that stream, since it's inherited from `sh -s` by Python (and therefore connected to our script text file), is the Python command `print("TESTPRINT")`.

The Python interpreter would then continue reading and executing commands from the script file until it runs out or executes the Python command `exit()`.

Comment: This is why languages like JCL (on IBM mainframes) and DCL (OpenVMS and some PDP-11 OSs) had each command start with a specific character.  In DCL, for example, it's `$`. Every line which does *not* start with a `$` is presumed to be program input, aka stdin.  This is a legacy of batch jobs and card decks.

Comment: IBM JCL still needs an explicit directive to read the next card as input.  `//SYSIN DD *`  see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.ieab600/iea3b6_Examples_of_SYSIN_DD_statements.htm

Comment: -1 for that first option, which opens up a big honking race condition exploit vulnerability in the delay between writing `script.py` and subsequently running it.

Comment: @Shadur Sure, but it would be easier for the attacker to just change the shell script, or run their own Python code, as they have already compromised the account.

Comment: Depending on where the script is written to - another big no-no in that example, because you don't specify a directory and don't test whether $CWD is writeable in the first place - they only need to be able to overwrite `script.py` which may not require account level access.

Comment: @Shadur Fixed it.

Comment: You should probably clean up and delete ``script.py`` after it runs.

Comment: @kmiklas That is reasonable.

Answer (score 20):

In addition to Kusalananda's answer, if you want the entire script to be run by python you can just change the first line to `#!/usr/bin/env python3` and run it like any normal shell script. That way you don't have to remember what script you have to run with which interpreter.

Comment: Even better, use `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, so that you use the system version of python3. See [this answer for why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-the-usr-bin-env-python-shebang-on-the-first-line-of-a-pyt).

Comment: @Jonathon Neat, I didn't know about that. Very useful!

Comment: Not sure how it applies to the OP's use case, since you have already defining it needs be using Bash.

Comment: @Paradox true, but a script with that shebang can be run in bash so I don't see how it would not apply?

Comment: @Akko Since OP is asking "within a Bash script", I might be missing something here, but I do not see how to put two shebang in a single script and then how it would apply.

Comment: @Paradox ok but the example in the question seems to run only python code so it's still possible OP or somebody else might find this information helpful

Answer (score 9):

You may also try the `<<<` (Here Strings) operator to save on lines:

```
$ python <<< 'print("MyTest")'
MyTest
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also set python path while calling the python file from bash script:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/tmp/python_dep.zip && python test_my.py
```